# Method parameter takes object from it's own class?

Tags: design, object-oriented

I'm not absolutely sure if this is the right place for this question. But I guess StackOverflow won't be the right place.

Is it for any reason a bad way to pass an object to a method from the same class? For some reason I don't feel well with the first solution.

The method `Start` starts the game with the given player.

```
CurrentGame.Start(CurrentGame.CurrentPlayer);
```

or

```
CurrentGame.StartWithCurrentPlayer();
```

But the last method could require a second method like:

```
public void SetCurrentPlayer(Player player)
{
    CurrentPlayer = player;
}
```

Comment: Does `Start` start the game with a given player as the one who goes first? Or does it start the player playing the game?

Comment: In this case the method starts the game with the given player.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A line such as `CurrentGame.CurrentPlayer` would be a code smell to me. In fact there's something fishy about the whole question.

You say that the second method, `StartWithCurrentPlayer`, would require an additional `SetCurrentPlayer` method. But how is that different from what `CurrentGame.CurrentPlayer` already is in the first method? Where does the value for `CurrentPlayer` come from?

There seem to be 3 possible scenarios here, none of which really make sense with either of your approaches:

1. *The game knows nothing about players until it's started.*

   In this scenario, I'd expect to see a method like this inside the `Game` class:

   ```
    public void Start(Player player)
    {
        // Set stuff up
        this.currentPlayer = player;
    }
   ```
2. *The player can be changed at any time.*

   This is a legitimate use case, e.g. arcade or multiplayer games. It's a little difficult to plan for, though. You'd have a class that looks like this:

   ```
    public void Start()
    {
        LoadLevel(CurrentPlayer.LastLevel);
        // Or whatever - some stuff that depends on CurrentPlayer
    }

    public Player CurrentPlayer
    {
        get { ... }
        set { ... }
    }
   ```

   You'd have to be very careful to make sure you do the proper setup/cleanup when `CurrentPlayer` is changed, otherwise I would foresee strange errors due to [Sequential Coupling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_coupling). For example, what happens when you try to start a game without setting *any* player? Still, this is a design decision, not necessarily an error.
3. *The player must be set up prior to starting a game.*

   This essentially means that the `Game` has no lifetime or meaning of its own without a `Player` object, which cries out for a dependency tree:

   ```
    public class Game
    {
        private readonly Player player;

        public Game(Player player)
        {
          if (player == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("player");
          this.player = player;
        }

        public void Start() { ... }
    }
   ```

Your first example violates the [Tell, Don't Ask](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/TellDontAsk.html) principle. You should never (well, rarely) need to call a method on an object and provide the *same object's data* as a parameter. That's exactly the kind of what OOP is designed to avoid with encapsulation.

Your original second example is similar to #2. It's potentially correct, but only if that is actually your intent, and it is also the most complicated.

Try to think about object lifetimes. #1 implies that the `Game` lasts forever, but if you switch the `Player` then you need to restart the game. #2 implies that the `Game` lasts forever but continues from its current point even when the `Player` is changed. And #3 implies that the `Player` may last a lot longer than the `Game` (for example a role-playing game). All are valid, but use the appropriate one for your particular situation.

Answer (score 3):

The first way seems best (`CurrentGame.Start(CurrentGame.CurrentPlayer);`). You can then feed it whatever player you want. it just happens by coincidence that your example uses an established player from your current scope.

Answer (score 2):

This depends, in part, on which piece of code is responsible for controlling who the current player is. Is it `CurrentGame` or the code that uses `CurrentGame` ("the caller")?

If `CurrentGame` is responsible for setting the next player after `CurrentPlayer`'s turn is over, then exposing `SetCurrentPlayer` would give the caller a way interfere with `CurrentGame`'s state. For example, if player A finishes her turn, `CurrentGame` would set the `CurrentPlayer` to Player B; however, the caller could use this method to set `CurrentPlayer` back to Player A before Player B's turn is over.

**If the caller is responsible:**

Your first option would be workable, although the caller might be overly dependent on using a property of CurrentGame to remember who was playing the last game.

**If `CurrentGame` is responsible:**

Consider a different approach, such as:

```
CurrentGame.SetPlayers(OrderedList<Player>)
```

The caller would pass in the list of players that is ordered according to the sequence of their turns. `CurrentGame` would just then set `CurrentPlayer` to the first player in the list when the game starts.

Comment: Your second paragraph is true but doesn't *necessarily* mean that anything is *wrong*. For example, many chess games will allow you to set up a board and then explicitly choose whose turn it is from a menu. It would be hard to encapsulate the menu choice into the game itself.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I'd go with the first option, because I find methods like the second option too specific. However if you had an array of players in your class, you could pass the array index instead.

Inside CurrentGame you would have something like the below for a four player game:

```
Player[] players = new Player[4];
```

Then to start the players:

```
CurrentGame.Start(0);
CurrentGame.Start(1);
CurrentGame.Start(2);
CurrentGame.Start(3);
```

Comment: But then I would need the player + the list to get the index. If somehow the same. Is it not so?

Answer (score 0):

First option is better as @brad already answered but i would like to suggest to not access `CurrentPlayer` explicitly but instead use a getter `getCurrentPlayer()`. IMHO you should have a setter too `setCurrentPlayer`. Maybe today you don´t have much computation to do and `setCurrentPlayer` is just an assignment as your example but if you already use setters / getters you have encapsulated all logic related to setCurrentPlayer inside a method.

Getters & Setters are a well known design pattern. You can find more about it here (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Getter/setter) for example.

Comment: CurrentPlayer has a public getter and a private setter. It's written in C# so I don't need extra methods.

Comment: @Lucas You did not mention before that it was C# neither there is a C# tag for this question. There is just a little sample of code too. By a design standpoint i think my suggestion is still valid as you said there are already getter / setter for CurrentPlayer.